# Insert PHP form data to google sheets

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, google-apps-script, google-sheets

We have one requirement similar to google forms, which will send the data to google Sheets.

Using PHP we built a web app(which acts like a google form that collects data from users eg Name, Email, etc) that will send output data(submits Multiple output responses in a single submit click ie array of responses, eg. output.1:- Name: john, Email: john@gmail.com, etc and output.2:- Name: sam, Email: sam@gmail.com, etc ) to the database, now the task is, we need to send the same data to google sheets using google sheets script URL instead of the database.

This is the code that we used to insert the web app's array of output data into the database

```
<?php 

insert.php

$connect = new PDO("mysql:host= localhost;dbname= ","user name","password");

$query = "
INSERT INTO expense 
(first_name, last_name, Category) 
VALUES (:first_name, :last_name, :Category)
";

for($count = 0; $count<count($_POST['hidden_first_name']); $count++)
{
    $data = array(
        ':first_name'   =>  $_POST['hidden_first_name'][$count],
        ':last_name'    =>  $_POST['hidden_last_name'][$count],
        ':Category' =>  $_POST['hidden_Category'][$count]
    );
    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute($data);
}

?>
```

So, we need the same kind of code which has to have the ability to send the obtained multiple output data ie array of responses (eg. output.1 : Name: john, Email: john@gmail.com, etc and output.2: Name: sam, Email: sam@gmail.com, etc from single submit click) from the web app to google sheet.

Comment: So what is your current problem with the google sheets API?

Comment: Hello @MarkusZeller, so currently as I mentioned we can insert the PHP form output array to MySQL but the problem is we are not into coding that much because it's not our domain but still now we have to work on it, so could you help me to write the code to insert the same PHP form output to a google sheet instead of MYSQL, and also I think we need to write a matching google script for google sheet to make it work with the code that inserts the output array to google sheet, @rajeshblake123@gmail.com is my Gmail ID if you want to connect with me, and thanks for the response man, I appreciate it.